# Uploading excel sheet in Java using blob or clob

Tags: java, upload, blob, xls, clob

I am new to java. I have a task of uploading Excel sheet to database (MySQL). Can anyone help me with the code ? Mention the steps and also suggest which jar file to use? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The keyword you are looking for is Java Database Connectivity or *JDBC*. It's Java's API to directly interact with any database. You'll need the MySQL connector to be able to use MySQL. There are tons of tutorials on the web on how to do this. Two that look helpful on first glance are:

- http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381/Using-JDBC-with-MySQL-Getting-Started.htm
- http://www.vogella.de/articles/MySQLJava/article.html

If you are new to MySQL, please read out the very good and comprehensive documentation of MySQL:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tutorial.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html